# how to make current primary key update itself instead of table generating a new primary key Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, insert-update

I have a application where stores can complete a questionnaire.

within this application I have two tables

1. `db.StoreAud(pk:AuditId) which contains all the stores information`
2. `db.storequests(pk:ReviewId) which holds the all questions information.
   AuditId is a foreign key in db.storequests table.`

Now here is the issue if a store complete the questionnaire the data saves perfectly in the database, however is the same store does the questionnaire again the db.storequests creates a new row in the database with a new primary key value  instead of updating the previous row.

Please check following image for more information, 
[image]

i would like the highlighted row to be updated the second row data.

Question is how can i update the previous row if the same store does the same questionnaire again. hope this made since.

> db.StoreAUD

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AuditId { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public int StoreNumber { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
```

> db.storequests

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }

    public int AuditId { get; set; }

    public int QuestionOne { get; set; }

    public string QuestionTwo { get; set; }
    public string QuestionThree { get; set; }
    public string QuestionFour { get; set; }
```

> controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(StoreQuestions storequestions) 
    {





        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            StoreAudit findingAudit = db.StoreAudit.Find(storequestions.AuditId); // grabbing the id from th store audit table
            findingAudit.ReadOnlyTickBox = true;
            db.StoreQuestions.Add(storequestions);



             db.SaveChanges();






            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Audit", new { id = storequestions.AuditId });
        }

        return View(storequestions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the entity state to modified instead of doing add.

Please find the sample example below

```
 StoreAudit findingAudit = db.StoreAudit.Find(storequestions.AuditId);
 findingAudit.ReadOnlyTickBox = true;
db.Entry(findingAudit ).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: by getting of the add method nothing is being updated or even adding to the database and also its the storequestions pk i am trying to update instead of the storeaudit table if you see what i mean